# setTimeout is not called when called from a static function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a utility typescript class with a static function called initTimer(), this function calls setTimeout. However when this static function called from react component the timer is not started!

> **StyleWrapper.tsx**

```
const StyleWrapper: FC = (props) => {
  const arrangeTiles = () => {
    StyleUtil.initTimer();
  };
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ arrangeTiles }}>
      <div id="cnplStyleWrapper">{props.children}</div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

> **StyleUtil.tsx**

```
export class StyleUtil{
    public static initTimer(){
      const timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Timeout Called!!");        
       }, 100);
    }
}
```

when I set timeout value to 0 then the console statement is logged in console but any value other than 0 the log statement is not logged in console. Weird, Am I missing something conceptually here?

Comment: your example doesn't call initTimer anywhere - the arrangeTiles function is never called. Could you provide a more complete example to show where you get this function from context and call it (if you are not doing that, then this is your problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think the calling method is a problem
`<Context.Provider value={{ arrangeTiles }}>`
you must call `arrangeTiles()` it is a method not a component